# Perl: How to "die" with no error message?

Tags: perl, die

I run a simple file test in perl with the code below:

```
my $f1 = "$pre_file";

 unless (-e $1) {

 print "\n Pre_check file does not exists! \n";

 die;

 }
```

It prints the following output:

> Pre_check file does not exists!
>   Died at ./huawei-postcheck line 81.

However I do not want the last line "Died at ./huawei-postcheck line 81.".

I want to to "die" with no error message.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just say

```
die "\n";
```

to suppress the message.

Answer (score 16):

See the documentation for [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html).

> If the last element of LIST does not end in a newline, the current
>   script line number and input line number (if any) are also printed,
>   and a newline is supplied.

So you can get die to work without printing anything by just using `die "\n"`. But given that you have an error message, I can't see why you don't use that.

```
unless (-e $f1) {
  die "\n Pre_check file does not exist!\n";
}
```

Of course, the difference is that the message will now go to STDERR rather than STDOUT. But that's probably the right place for it to go.

Answer (score 9):

use [`exit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html) instead of `die`.

Comment: @Arkadiy, `die` actually uses `$! || $?>>8 || 255`, if you want to emulate it.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to `exit 1` instead of dying then.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $f1 = "$pre_file";

unless (-e $1) {
    print "\n Pre_check file does not exists! \n";
    exit 1;
}
```