# suppress stderr from perl DBI execute

Tags: perl, dbi

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(q{
  INSERT INTO sales (product_code, qty, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
}) or die $dbh->errstr;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my ($product_code, $qty, $price) = split /,/;
    $sth->execute($product_code, $qty, $price) or die $dbh->errstr;
}
$dbh->commit or die $dbh->errstr;
```

I dont want to show stderr from $sth->execute on console. how to supress it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perl: How to "die" with no error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820344/perl-how-to-die-with-no-error-message)

Comment: after removing die $sth->execute($product_code, $qty, $price) ,                                     i want to suppress stderr from $sth->execute , no errors should be printed on console

Comment: What goes to `STDERR` stream can be controlled, to a good extent, by writing a  `$SIG{__WARN__}` hook.  See `%SIG` hash in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar#General-Variables).  (But I am not sure what exactly you are asking...)

Comment: Consider that someone else might want the errors although in your use case you don't. That might mean leaving it alone and redirecting standard output to the null device. The warnings are there when you want them though.

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by the [PrintWarn](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#PrintWarn) and [PrintError](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#PrintError) settings for DBI handles.  I generally turn them off globally when establishing the initial database connection (`$dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $user, $pass, { PrintWarn => 0, PrintError => 0 });`) because I prefer to do my own error-handling and reporting, but it is also possible to set them on a per-statement level, turn them off for a single `execute` and back on afterward, etc. by using the [set_err](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#set_err) method.